# Page not found (404) Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.html/

Tags: python, django

im trying to create simple todo list. I've found a little issue. During deleting todo task I'm getting error (this from topic), but task is actually deleting. How to get rid of this error?

urls.py

```
    from django.urls import path, include
    from .views import DeleteTodo
    from . import views
    
    
    app_name = 'todoxd_app'
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index, name='index'),
        path('todo/', views.todo, name='todo'),
        path('new_todo/', views.new_todo, name='new_todo'),
        path('delete/<int:pk>/', DeleteTodo.as_view() ,name='delete_todo'),
    ]
```

delete_todo.html

```
    
    
    
        
        Title
    
    
         {% extends 'todoxd_app/base.html' %}
    
        {% block content %}
    
            
                {% csrf_token %}
    
    
                Are you sure you want to delete this task?
                DELETE TASK
    
            
    
        {% endblock content %}
```

views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from django.urls import reverse_lazy
    from .models import Task
    from .forms import TaskForm
    from django.views.generic import DeleteView
    
    def index(request):
        return render(request, 'todoxd_app/index.html')
    
    def todo(request):
        objekt = Task.objects.all()
        context = {'objekt': objekt}
        return render(request, 'todoxd_app/todo.html', context)
    
    def new_todo(request):
        if request.method != 'POST':
            form = TaskForm()
        else:
            form = TaskForm(data=request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('todoxd_app/new_todo')
    
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'todoxd_app/new_todo.html', context)
    
    class DeleteTodo(DeleteView):
        model = Task
        template_name = 'todoxd_app/delete_todo.html'
        success_url = '/index.html/'
```

urls from django project

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path, include
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('', include('todoxd_app.urls')),
        path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    ]
```

If you will find other issue, give me feedback, I'm just a begginer. Thanks!

Comment: can you show you urls.py file from your django project.

Comment: `/index.html/` is not a route in your urls.py? Just set success_url to `/`?

Comment: you are redirecting to `/index.html/` (see `DeleteTodo.success_url`) after deleting the record, but `/index.html/` is nowhere to be found in your `urls.py`

Comment: It should be `localhost:8000` without `index.html`

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your `success_url`.

Since your app's home page defined as :

```py
path('', views.index, name='index')
```

you can edit as :

```py
success_url = "/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line from

```
success_url = '/index.html/'
```

to

```
success_url = 'index' # this is the name of the url path in your urls.py
```

also you can change this line

```
return redirect('todoxd_app/new_todo')
```

to

```
return redirect('new_todo') # again the same thing.... name of the url path in your urls.py file
```

Comment: well u dont have a function in the class. your code is incomplete

Comment: I've seen some people don' t used they own function, but a reverse_lazy from django.urls, but it's not working in my project